# Vosk gives error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, vosk

So basically, I have this speech recognition software in Python which worked flawlessly then my drive died and I had to buy a new one, reinstalled Windows, reinstalled Python (same version), and pip install vosk, then tried to run it. Now it all the sudden doesn't work at all does this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Software\Voxy\src\master.py", line 1, in <module>
    from vosk import SetLogLevel as vosk_log_level
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vosk\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .vosk_cffi import ffi as _ffi
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vosk\vosk_cffi.py", line 2, in <module>
    import _cffi_backend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

I have tried "pip install cffi" but it still doesn't work. Another weird thing is if I write pip show vosk, it says:

```
Name: vosk
Version: 0.3.32
Summary: Offline open source speech recognition API based on Kaldi and Vosk
Home-page: https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api
Author: Alpha Cephei Inc
Author-email: contact@alphacephei.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: c:\users\james\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: cffi
Required-by:
```

Why is saying it's installed in the anaconda3 library all the sudden, while also appearantly being found in the Python site-packages? It somehow seems like pip install/show/uninstall and actually running a Python scripts only co-operates like 50% somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i just crated a folder junction from the python site-packages to the Anaconda site-packages folder.